# how to sync recomposition with state change?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

i have list of items when i delete item<id,content> by it's id it delete related from DB and state list but in ui delete  last added item
id[in attached image if i click delete node 2 it's id will deleted but node 3 will be removed from ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9NOI.jpg) 
when i repoen the screen the ture list <with items 1,3> will shown

```kotlin
//UI File
val state = boardSessionViewModel.sessionState.value

  state.nodes.forEach {
                            MultipleDraggableObject(
                                nodeItem = NodeItem(it.content, id = it.id),
                                onDeleteNode = { nodeId ->
                                    boardSessionViewModel.onBoardEvent(
                                        BoardSessionEvent.DeleteNode(
                                            nodeId
                                        )
                                    )
                                },
                                isSaving = isInSaving
                            )
                        }
```

```kotlin
class BoardSessionViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val boardSessionUseCases: BoardSessionUseCases,
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle) :ViewModel() {

    private val _state = mutableStateOf(BoardSessionState())
    val sessionState: State<BoardSessionState> = _state

    var sid = mutableStateOf(savedStateHandle.get<String>("sessionId"))

    private var getNodesJob: Job? = null

    init {
        getNodes(sessionId = sid.value!!)
    }

    fun onBoardEvent(sessionEvent: BoardSessionEvent){
        when(sessionEvent){
            is BoardSessionEvent.AddNode -> {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                sessionEvent.node.sessionId = sid.value!!
                boardSessionUseCases.addNode(sessionEvent.node)
            }
            }
            is BoardSessionEvent.DeleteNode -> {
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    boardSessionUseCases.deleteNode(sessionEvent.nodeId)
                }
            }
            is BoardSessionEvent.UpdateNode -> {
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    boardSessionUseCases.updateNode(sessionEvent.content,sessionEvent.nodeId)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private fun getNodes(sessionId:String) {
        getNodesJob?.cancel()
        getNodesJob = boardSessionUseCases.getNodes(sessionId)
            .onEach { nodes ->
                _state.value = _state.value.copy(
                   nodes = nodes
                )
            }
            .launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }


}
```

Comment: You're modifying `BoardSessionUseCases`, to trigger recomposition you need to update `_state`.

Comment: You might find the following article helpful: https://dev.to/zachklipp/two-mutables-dont-make-a-right-2kgp

As @PylypDukhov mentions, Compose is observing the mutable state value not what it contains. The above article explains what is happening and gives you options to fix it.